# Reversing Camera fitting Problems with Trigger supply

Tags: ford, focus, reverse-lights

I am installing a reversing camera in my 2002 Ford Focus Automatic. When I connect to the reversing light wire by means of a piggyback fuse holder. When you engage reverse the camera works fine but neither the reversing light or the reversing sensors work. When I remove the trigger connection the rev light and sensors work as normal.
Does the engine management detect there is an additional demand on the reversing light system.
I would welcome answers please.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Are you connecting them in series ? If you can draw the circuit it would help

Answer (score 1):

If the connector you are using is not the issue, and some of these are so cheap (I won't use them) then it may be that the camera demand is triggering odd behaviour.

So, I would use the reverse light feed to control a relay which then feeds the camera trigger supply. The 4 terminal relay is simple and adequate for that job.

Comment: Thanks for the Tip a relay sounds like a good answer.